What is the point of using two arrays in Spectre attack?
Spectre attack suggest the following approach to fetch secret data from the memory:
if (x < array1_size)
  y = array2[array1[x] * 4096];

More detailed explanation says:

Consequently, the speculative execution logic adds x to the base address of array1 and requests the data at the resulting address from the memory subsystem. This read is a cache hit, and quickly returns the value of the secret byte k. The speculative execution logic then uses k to compute the address of array2[k * 4096]. It then sends a request to read this address from memory (result-ing in a cache miss)..

What I am missing here is why do we move from obtaining k to using k as an address that we're trying to read.
As it looks to me we take out-of-bound x and get some unknown value k from that memory address array1 + x. Then we use that value k as the offset for array2 base address (array2 + k).
So why do we move from base array1 + x to base array2 + k? Why cant we just come up with a single array?

It requires the second indirection to work. Speculative execution effectively obtains the value of byte k directly from cache which can then be determined indirectly by looking for the resulting cache miss fetching an element of array2[k*4096]. By the time memory protection kicks in the data has already leaked.
